# How can I check from the command line to see if FFMpeg is actively playing audio?

Tags: ffmpeg

Ffmpeg is showing its playing an icecast stream but there is no audio coming out. Restarting the program produces audio again. If an icecast feed goes away, ffmpeg keeps running even though theres no audio for some reason.

I need to detect this and restart it if theres an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set stimeout to e.g. 1000000 (10 seconds) - then ffmpeg will quit if it doesn't get any further data in 10 seconds. Then you can e.g. run ffmpeg into a loop.

Comment: Looks like thats only for rtsp?

Comment: ah, icecast seems to use http (shoutcast uses this as well) for streaming to client. Then the option is called timeout ;) For this protocoll, ffmpeg supports some reconnect_* options as well (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http)